# Python Undefined variable detected by Pylint but code still runs

Tags: python-3.x, variables, scope

This Python3 code finishes running, but I get an error message from Pylint and I do not know why.
Any solution would be greatly appreciated.
Also if you happen to know a better way to generate dynamic variables, please do share your wisdom. I understand that dynamic names for variables might not be the best practice, but I do need dynamic names for variables for what I am doing. I just need no errors also... Is this a problem in my code or is it a bug in the Pylint extension?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
list_of_items_without_variable = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']

# I want each item in list to be dynamically assigned a unique variable so that: variable_0 = 'apple', variable_1 = 'banana', variable_2 = 'orange'
# That way I can access them in code later by unique variable instead of list_of_items_without_variable[0], list_of_items_without_variable[1] etc

# My solution
for index, item in enumerate(list_of_items_without_variable):
    globals()['variable_' + str(index)] = item

print(variable_0)
print(variable_1)
print(variable_2)

# This code works and python file executes and finishes running.
""" 
I am on Linux Mint 20.01 VScodium with extension Python and additional Pylint
With the extension python disabled, I get no error messages
With the extension python enabled, I get this problem:


After saving this file, variable_0, variable_1, variable_2 are UNDERLINED in RED for some reason?!?!?
After execution of python file, I get the following notification alert in PROBLEMS section of VScodium:

Undefined variable 'variable_0'
{
    "resource": "/my_folder/global.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "undefined-variable",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined variable 'variable_0'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 7
}

Undefined variable 'variable_1'
{
    "resource": "/my_folder/global.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "undefined-variable",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined variable 'variable_1'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 11,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 11,
    "endColumn": 7
}

Undefined variable 'variable_2'
{
    "resource": "/my_folder/global.py",
    "owner": "python",
    "code": "undefined-variable",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Undefined variable 'variable_2'",
    "source": "pylint",
    "startLineNumber": 12,
    "startColumn": 7,
    "endLineNumber": 12,
    "endColumn": 7
}

"""
```

Comment: I don't see it as a bug in either your code or the linter. Your code works and the linter is looking at the page lexically rather than executing your code so would not understand the existence of `variable_0`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am beginning to suspect that too.